# Custom table view cells show up blank (labels are nil)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I'm using the same code that I use for other tables in my app, but I'm missing something here. None of my labels are being set as you can see in this image.

[image: nil UILabels]

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    CommissionsCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CommissionsCell"];
    CommissionInfo* tmpInfo = [g_commissionList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.95 alpha:1 ];

    cell.lblDescription.text = tmpInfo.description;
    cell.lblDate.text = tmpInfo.date;
    cell.lblStatus.text = tmpInfo.status;

    if([tmpInfo.imgThumbPath isEqualToString:@""]){
        cell.lblInstructions.hidden=NO;
    }else{
        cell.lblInstructions.hidden=YES;
    }


    [cell.btnImg setImage:tmpInfo.img_thumb];
    return cell;
}
```

I have all of my labels mapped in the CommissionsCell.h file any idea what's causing this?

[image: Cell setup]

Comment: Do you use storyboards ?

Comment: Are your labels properly connected/instantiated?

Comment: Where are you making your cell's view? Also, did you register the class?

Comment: If you are using Storyboard, then the cell needs to be connected properly for them to get instantiated

If you are not using storyboard then you need to instantiating the cell programmatically [alloc and init it].

Comment: Thank you all for your reply. I am using storyboards. I reconnected my labels in the CommissionsCell.h file. What do you mean by registering the class?

Comment: I mean use registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:, which you shouldn't do, if you made your cell in the storyboard.